# What are the origins of the swords of Grayskull?

Tags: he-man

In the *Masters of the Universe* franchise, the Sword of Power and Sword of Protection are the magical weapons which can channel the Power of Grayskull, the Castle which is the center point for all magic on Eternia, into a hero; the Sword of Power turns Prince Adam into He-Man, and the Sword of Protection (in most franchises outside of *She-Ra & the Princesses of Power*) turns Adora into She-Ra. As of the 2002 *He-Man & the Masters of the Universe* reboot, it was *implied* that the Power sword imbibes Adam with the enhanced power of his ancestor, the Warrior-Mage King Grayskull, but nothing specific was given to the sword's origin.

Granted that the *original* **MOTU** toyline story is somewhat different (He-Man and Skeletor each have a half of a sword which is the key to Grayskull, which holds universal power), so that lore is somewhat different, but after the first cartoon, things started to fall more in line with that. And it still didn't *say* much about how the swords were created and who made them.

Is there any information as to the sword's forging?

Comment: They were forged in the Fires of Mah-tell with the goal of creating the Dolah Grean

Comment: @Valorum OMG, dude, you is a **Fool** when you are ready, lol!

Comment: This question seems to be more or less resolved in the new Masters of the Universe:Revelation, on Netflix.